# openCV: Как вытащить кадр из видео файла?

Tags: c++, python, c, opencv

А возможно ли вытаскивать кадры из локального видео т.е. того, которое хранится на компьютере. А то нашел много тем с получением кадров из веб-камеры, но, к сожалению, ничего не нашел о локальном видео.

Желательно на python, хотя язык программирования не важен, интересует сама возможность.

Comment: [возможно](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5768/how-can-i-get-one-single-frame-from-a-video-file/)

Comment: Спасибо Bezarius. Буду пробовать.
p.s. нужен именно OpenCV, т.к. основная работа будет происходить именно с изображениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно решить задачу именно с помощью openCV, то получить доступ к локальному файлу можно так:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.avi')
```

дальше можете работать так же как с камерой.

А вообще, OpenCV немного для другого, возможно вам стоит воспользоваться ffmpeg'ом:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i Underworld.Awakening.avi -frames:v 1 out1.jpg
```